# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: protractor, protractor-net

Currently i am working protractor UI testing. My testcase is working properly so far, but suddenly it shows a webdriver problem. My current chrome version is 84. But the selenium driver is expecting version 85. Version 85 is still not released.

```
[14:56:46] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
  (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
[14:56:46] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
  (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Hello Aravind, I edited your question for a more readable experience. Anyways, you should edit your question, adding more information about what you are doing, and what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: just install chromedriver 84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use webdriver-manager to specify your chromedriver version or use --webdriverUpdate=false if running e2e tests

(see: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5460)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue where [webdriver-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager) is installing ChromeDriver 85 even though Chrome 84 is the current stable release. Multiple people have reported this issue.

I've posted [a workaround in issue 376](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/376#issuecomment-663560439)

Overall, you temporarily can hardcode the version you want when using webdriver-manager, then tell protractor which version to use (since protractor can still try to install 85 and use it).

Here is the copied work-around:

1. We have webdriver-manager installed as project dependency (`npm install --save-dev webdriver-manager`)
2. we call `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 84.0.4147.30` prior to running our tests. This will install the 84 chromedriver version in ./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/. (We just made this as a npm script in our package.json)
3. We then update the protractor.conf file to have this line in the root of exports.config: `chromeDriver:"./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30.exe"`**

Protractor still installs chromedriverr 85, but it will use the 84 version.

** In our case, we run our protractor tests in docker, but develop mostly on windows. So I updated the protractor.conf to have this line so that it works in either:
`chromeDriver: process.platform === "win32" ? "./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30.exe" : "./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30"`

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue but it worked when I updated latest version of protractor which is 7.0.0